# Image Denoising Algorithm Confusion

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have written a denoising algorithm that does work upon testing for an image but it's not working for all types of images and constantly shows an error message:

Attempt to grow array along ambiguous dimension.

Error in pmf(line 14)
A(i-p,j-p)=mean(R2);

I'm attaching my function below:

```
function X=pmf(A)
A=double(A);
 for p=5:-1:1  
  pA=padarray(A,[p p],'symmetric');
  pB=(pA~=0 & pA~=255);
  [m,n]=size(pB);
  for i=1+p:m-p
    for j=1+p:n-p       
       if (pB(i,j)==0)          
            for k=1:p
                if (isequal(pB(i-k:i+k,j-k:j+k),zeros(2*k+1,2*k+1))~=1)             
                     R1=pA(i-k:i+k,j-k:j+k);
                     R2=R1(R1>0 & R1<255);
                     A(i-p,j-p)=mean(R2);
                     break;
                end
            end
       end
    end 
  end   
 end
  X=uint8(A);
end
```

I was trying to apply my denoising algorithm to denoise the image and compare it with built in noise filter functions but I keep receiving the error message continuously. I even resized images to 512x512 pixels yet I keep getting the same error.

Comment: What are the values of `A`, `i`, `j`, `p` and `mean(R2)` when the error occurs? Use `dbstop if error` before running your program. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buzezti-1

Comment: A = 512x512x3
i = 65
j = 1542
p = 5
R2 = 19

Comment: So, you're trying to assign a value to `A(60, 1537)` when `A` has 3 dimensions, not 2, and the number of columns in your image is 512, which is much less than 1537. It is actually valid (although confusing) to reference an element in a 3-dimensional array using only 2 indices, in which case the last index is treated as a linear index to the remaining dimensions. In this case, the column number would be `mod(1537, 512) == 1` and the channel number would be `ceil(1537/512) == 4`. As you can see, you're failing by trying to access the pixel one index past the last valid one.

Comment: how do I correct my code in that case? I've tested the same algorithm for another picture and it worked fine but when I select a different test picture, it's showing an error.